# How to get domain and range of a property and its "Sub Properties" in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, ontology

I'm sorry if my question is bad. I am a beginner.
I have an ontology made by [protégé](http://protege.stanford.edu) and its default prefix.(SPARQL v1.0)

Suppose in my ontology I have a class named `washingMachine` and a class named `Country`, that `washingMashine` and `Country` are connected by an object property named `MadeIN`. `MadeIN` is sub property of another object property named `hasProperty`.

I want to write a query to find domain and range of `hasProperty` but unfortunately `MadeIN` does not appear.  What is its query, please?

This is the query I've written:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ?domain ?range ?labeldomain ?labelrange
where {
    owl:hasPropertyOf rdfs:domain ?domain ;
                      rdfs:range ?range .
    ?domain rdfs:label ?labeldomain.
    ?range rdfs:label ?labelrange.
}
```

and ontology:

```
 <ObjectProperty rdf:about="&owl;hasPropertyOf">

    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&owl;aqua"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&owl;varioPerfect"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&owl;ماشين_لباسشويي"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&owl;مصرف_انرژی"/>
    <propertyChainAxiom rdf:parseType="Collection">
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/yaali/ontologies/2014/10/untitled-ontology-11#madeIN"/>
    </propertyChainAxiom>
</ObjectProperty>
```

Comment: Are you sure the domain and range are defined? Having a property as a sub property of another, does not imply that the domain or range of the parent property is the child property. You need to specify concepts as domain and range of a property. Are they defined?

Comment: thank you to answer. yes i did. look at the query i added , it dosen't show MadeIN.

Comment: Can you show a fragment of your ontology that shows how the domain and the range are defined?

Comment: In any case, in your question text, you are referring to something called `hasProperty` (presumeably from a custom namespace of yours?), while in your SPARQL query, you refer to `hasPropertyOf` ... from the OWL namespace. Even though that identifier seems to be non-existent in [this OWL reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-quick-reference-20121211/). Please clarify what you are using and how it is defined.

Comment: Also, please clarify what you are looking for - why do you expect `MadeIN` to appear? you are not querying for any properties, you are using one fixed property and querying for its domain and range.

Comment: i didn' t define my own namespace. i dont know what it is at all! i just want to know what is query of asking for domain and range of a property and all its sub properties.

Comment: here is a part of my ontology in RDF/XML format: <!-- http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#hasPropertyOf -->

    <ObjectProperty rdf:about="&owl;hasPropertyOf">
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/yaali/ontologies/2014/10/untitled-ontology-11#ابعاد"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&owl;ماشين_لباسشويي"/>
               <propertyChainAxiom rdf:parseType="Collection">
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/yaali/ontologies/2014/10/untitled-ontology-11#madeIN"/>
        </propertyChainAxiom>
    </ObjectProperty>

Comment: Edit your question and add the ontology to it. It is unreadable here.